# Binding of DNS Servers to Interfaces

Tags: linux, windows-10, networking, dns, network-adapter

I am deliberately leaving my platform unspecified for this question, though I will say that my "platforms of interest" are Linux and Windows 10.

Suppose I have N NICs. Each is connected to separate networks, one of which provides Internet access via a default gateway. The other networks are all private and have no path to the Internet or to each other. All networks use RFC 1918 address space. The host is **not** set up to route among the networks.

Each private network has a unique domain name associated with it and runs its own private authoritative DNS servers to serve up DNS records for that unique domain name. These names are not part of the global DNS. (I assure this by making them subdomains of a domain I have registered and for which I run public authoritative DNS servers that **don't** serve records for the mentioned subdomains.)

Suppose that the network numbers and associated domain names are as follows:

- **my-unique-subdomain-1.my-unique-domain.com**

  - Hosts reside in **10.0.1.0/24**
  - My host has IP address **10.0.1.1** on interface **eth1**
  - DNS servers are at **10.0.1.253** and **10.0.1.254**
- **my-unique-subdomain-2.my-unique-domain.com**

  - Hosts reside in **10.0.2.0/24**
  - My host has IP address **10.0.2.1** on interface **eth2**
  - DNS servers are at **10.0.2.253** and **10.0.2.254**
- ...
- **my-unique-subdomain-N.my-unique-domain.com**

  - Hosts reside in **10.0.N.0/24**
  - My host has IP address **10.0.N.1** on interface **ethN**
  - DNS servers are at **10.0.N.253** and **10.0.N.254**

As shown above, my host has two DNS servers (primary and secondary) associated with each interface. These could be assigned via DHCP or manually; it really doesn't matter. My ISP's DNS servers will be associated with the network interface through which the Internet can be reached. My private DNS servers for the private networks will be associated with the other network interfaces.

I am having difficulty understanding how my host can know which DNS server to use to resolve a given domain name. Any given FQDN that is actually defined can be resolved over exactly one network interface---either via the appropriate private DNS server or, if none apply, via a public DNS server. To know which DNS server to use, the host has to know which network number the host being queried resides on, but to know that, it has to first make a DNS query! There seems to be a chicken and egg problem here.

Suppose I want to resolve **foo.my-unique-subdomain-3.my-unique-domain.com**. How does my host determine that it needs to send the query to the DNS server at **10.0.3.253** or **10.0.3.254**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll list three possible solutions, one for Windows and two platform-agnostic.
Of course, that list is not exhaustive.

- The easiest solution (Windows and Linux):

Edit the `hosts` file on your PC. In Linux, it is something like `/etc/hosts`; in Windows, it is usually `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Please note that you must be `root` or `Administrator`, respectively, to edit it, and under Windows, you might have to temporarily disable your virus scanner to do that.

The hosts file is meant to provide DNS resolving without a DNS server. It usually takes entries which will never change. For the format, take a look into the respective file which already exists on your O/S. It is very easily understandable.

- An easy, but nearly unknown solution (only Windows)

Windows provides `NRPT` (Name Policy Resolution Table). This does exactly what you want: You can use different name servers depending on the name which should be resolved. Because it allows wildcards in the configuration, it is very easy to configure; the configuration is done via GUI and in your case consists of one line per subnet.

The drawback is that GUI configuration happens via group policy, so you can't do it easily in Windows Home. When doing your research about NRPT, don't worry about the complicated stuff; most articles concentrate on its usage for direct access, DNSSEC and other aspects. But you can really forget about that (if you don't need it) and use NRPT just as described above only for the purpose you want.

[Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee649241(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) is a starting point about it.

- A good, but not-that-easy generic solution (Windows and Linux)

While this solution is generic (works with any O/S), the actual steps to implement it differ not only between O/Ss, but also between the software used. Therefore, I'll explain it with Linux and `bind9`, but you can easily transfer the method into other environments.

The basic idea is to install an additional, fully configurable DNS server (or just a resolver) on your host, and to configure your host's networks to use that DNS server (or resolver) to resolve all names. Then, configure the DNS server / resolver to forward DNS queries accordingly.

In the last years, `Unbound` has gained a lot of attention, but I don't know it, so I'll explain how this would work with Linux / `bind9`. I'll leave it to you to look up the configuration syntax details in its man page and reference manual, and show only the crucial steps.

First, install `bind9`, preferably using the packet manager of your Linux distribution. Configure it to listen on all network interfaces, including `127.0.0.1`. Then, in your host's network configuration, enter `127.0.0.1` as DNS server.

Then, in `bind`'s zone configuration, place snippets like

```
zone "my-unique-subdomain-1.my-unique-domain.com" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 10.0.1.253; 10.0.1.254 };
};
```

When trying to resolve a host name, the host will now query itself (i.e. the `bind9` DNS server). `bind9` will determine the host name's zone, lookup the respective zone configuration (if it exists) and will forward the query to the forwarder which is configured for that zone.

You can do the same under Windows with appropriate software, but this is usually not necessary due to `NRPT`.

As a final note, you can of course have `bind9` listen on `127.0.0.1` only (instead of on all network interfaces), which would ensure that it can't reached by other hosts. This may or may not be desirable in your situation.

Comment: Thank you for the great reference to NRPT! Had never heard of it. The linked document states:

Comment: "In the absence of the NRPT, the client will operate in a normal fashion."

Comment: In Windows, what is the "normal fashion" for the case I described?

Comment: @Dave The normal fashion is using the standard name server. That means that you should put your internet provider's name server into your network configuration (on each interface, via DHCP or as static configuration) because this standard name server will be used to resolve names which don't match a pattern in the NRPT. In the NRPT, you *only* put the name servers which resolve your internal names.

Comment: But what I'm getting at is not what I *could* do to force things to work the way I want, but rather to understand what Windows *will* do if configured as I originally described (i.e. without NRPT).

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. It is definitely not possible to achieve what you want without further settings or further software. So the answer to your question (*How does my host determine ...*) is that this question is invalid, because it implies that your host *can* determine .... But in fact, it can't, unless you take further steps some of which I have described.

Comment: The following happens: Windows chooses one of the DNS servers and tries to resolve the host name. Unless that server *accidentally* is the one which can resolve the host name, it either refuses the action immediately, or it runs into a network timeout when trying to resolve the name, depending on its configuration. The type of reply may influence your host's behavior, e.g. whether to give up or to try the DNS servers on the other interfaces. This is impossible to tell without knowing your DNS servers' configuration. In every case, you will get into serious trouble (at least, long timeouts).